# operator precedence in C++ expressions

Tags: c++, operators, expression

**Program 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a = 5;
int fun1() {
    a = 17;
    return 3;
} 

int main() {
// Even though C languages are left associative, 
// this line of code evaluates fun1() first: 
    a = a + fun1();
//  a = 17+3
    printf("%d",a);
    a = fun1()+a;
    printf("\n%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

20

20

**Program 2:**

```
int a = 10;
int fun(){
    a= 15;
    return 30;
}
int main(void) {
// whereas in this example, fun() is evaluated last:
    int x = a + 10 + fun();
//      x = 10 + 10 + 30
    a= 10;
    int y = fun() + 10 + a;
    printf(" x = %d \n y = %d \n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

x = 50

y = 55

Why does program 1 evaluate fun1() first whereas in program 2 fun() is evaluated last when it is placed at the end of the expression?

From what I understand, C-based languages are left associative so why is program 1 behaving weird?

Comment: The evaluation order is unspecified. It is up to the compiler.

Comment: @drescherjm I still don't understand, the order of operands is the same in both programs

Comment: "operator precedence in C++ expressions": http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: The compiler is free to evaluate it in either order.

Comment: Precedence is not the same as evaluation order, and neither is the same as associativity.

Comment: @drescherjm I understand that, what i don't understand is this: what makes it "choose" an order?

Comment: ***i don't understand is this: what makes it "choose" an order?*** It's optimizer.

Comment: Not all things in the language are (fully) specified. Many things are left up to the implementation or entirely undefined. Order of evaluation is one thing that is (in many cases, although C++17 narrows it somewhat) left up to the implementation - meaning the compiler can in many situations evaluate left to right, right to left or even mix - as it pleases - you *cannot* rely on the order.

Comment: Operator precedence and order of evaluations are 2 different almost unrelated concepts

Answer (score 3):

Historically, order of arguments evaluation of a function call was unspecified. That means that for the call

```
foo(bar(), baz());
```

it was left up to the compiler if it needs to call `bar()`, than `baz()`, or the other way around. Keep in mind that calling an operator is another case of a generic function call, i.e. `baz() + bar()` is semantically the same as `operator+(baz(), bar())`.

For practical purposes, compilers used to evaluate arguments from last to first, given the fact that this is the order of pushing arguments to the stack for many function call ABIs.

Comment: @drescherjm I am not sure if anybody would really benefit from that. Most devs are too trained to rely on order of evaluation, so they are unlikely to start using this guarantee.

Comment: @liliscent I stand corrected. Looks like I misunderstood the wording. WIll remove the part about C++17. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You mixed 2 concepts (it happens quite often though), let's look to expression:

```
a = b + c + d * e;
```

operator precedence and associativity means, that this expression is equal to

```
a = ( ( b + c ) + ( d * e ) );
```

but it does not mean for example, that `d * e` must be evaluated before `b + c`, just because * has higher precedence. Details can be found here [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

> Except where noted below, there is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in C++. This is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators: the expression f1() + f2() + f3() is parsed as (f1() + f2()) + f3() due to left-to-right associativity of operator+, **but the function call to f3 may be evaluated first, last, or between f1() or f2() at run time**.

emphasis is mine.

Answer (score 0):

There are three separate concepts that frequently get confused:

*Evaluation order*, which determines in which order *operands* are evaluated.

This is usually left unspecified in the standard.

*Precedence*, which determines which of two *operators* is evaluated first.

For instance, in `a + b * c`, the multiplication is evaluated before the addition.
The evaluation order of the operands is not affected by precedence.

*Associativity*, which determines which operator *of the same precedence* is evaluated first.

For instance, `<<` is left-associative; `a << b << c` is evaluated as `(a << b) << c`, while assignment is right-associative; `a = b = c` is `a = (b = c)`.
The evaluation order of the operands is not affected by associativity either.

Answer (score -2):

evaluation order of this type are not specified by standard. it is up to the compiler to do the optimization he is doing.

Comment: what does that mean? what makes the compiler evaluate fun1() first even though it is at the end of the expression? I used the same compiler for both programs.

Comment: it mean what it is. you can't rely on order of evaluation in this kind of expression, if you do want you must add () in the correct places.